# Reusable Components for iOS

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I'm a iOS Application developer.I need some similar tasks in many projects as example i need image slideshow i have developed slideshow and when i need that  coping code into viewController class and using it.
My question is, it is possible to create my own controllers,then i can drag and drop component using IB and use it same as UITableViewCell. if it is impossible is there any easy way to reuse existing components in new projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many developers organize reusable code in static libraries in iOS.  Here's a good [tutorial](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/)